# How can I undelete an accidentally deleted post?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, undelete

I have read that in order to undelete a post, I must flag one of my other posts and inform a moderator that I would like the deleted post undeleted. Unfortunately, that was my very first question, so the raison d'etre of this post is simply that I may get that other post undeleted.

I would like to undelete it because I found a solution to my issue and think it would be potentially beneficial for others to see the answer.

Link to the post: [Passing a two-dimensional array for threaded processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241717/passing-a-two-dimensional-array-for-threaded-processing)

Comment: It has been undeleted for you; three higher-rep users have voted to undelete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** I just checked your profile and your question has been undeleted.

You've done the right thing!

Asking a question on your site's meta is the way to get things done when you need help.  Asking in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) also works, but you'll need [20 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/chat) before you can talk there.

For some issues (e.g. Forgetting your password, getting unbanned, asking to merge accounts, etc) the [Contact Us](https://stackoverflow.com/help) link at the bottom of every SE site is the place to go.

[image]